# Pointer to vector iteration

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, iteration

I have some trouble iterating through a vector.
I have a class which contains a vector. The vector contains objects of the type Artikel (another class is made). The idea is that when i call ".getArtikels" it returns a pointer to the vector (as seen in class.cpp). Then i iterate through the vector and call "getname" of the objects in the vector.

The error i get is:

> left of '->begin' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
>   left of '->end' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

function showarticles in main:

```
int showarticles()
{
    for (vector<Artikel>::iterator i = BC.getArtikels->begin(); i != BC.getArtikels->end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << i->getName() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**class.h**

```
public:
    vector<Artikel> const * getArtikels() const;

private:
    vector<Artikel> Artikels;
```

**class.cpp**

```
vector<Artikel> const* Bandencentrale::getArtikels() const
{
    return &Artikels;
}
```

I stripped the code and left the parts that seemed necessary.

EDIT:

I forgot to call the getArtikels function and because i returned a const i had to edit the iterator:

function showarticles in main:

```
int showarticles()
{
    for (vector<Artikel>::const_iterator i = BC.getArtikels()->**c**begin(); i != BC.getArtikels->cend(); ++i)
    {
        cout << i->getName() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call the `getArtikels` function:

```
BC.getArtikels()->begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this program :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    string name;
    public:
    A(string n): name(n) {}
    const string getName() const
    {
        return name;
    }
};
class B
{
    vector<A> v;
    public:
    void getv(int);
    vector<A> const* getArtikel() const;
};
void B :: getv(int n)
    {
        string s;
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            cin>>s;
            v.push_back(s);
        }
    }
vector<A> const* B :: getArtikel() const
{
    return &v;
}
void show(B bc)
{
    for (auto i = bc.getArtikel()->begin(); i!=bc.getArtikel()->end(); ++i)
    {
        cout<<i->getName()<<endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
    B obj;
    obj.getv(5);
    cout<<endl;
    show(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

This will give your desired output. Now one problem is your usage of `getArtikel` function as you have missed the parenthesis ie `()`. Rest all errors you can check from my code. If you have queries feel free to ask !!!